# How to used proguard in my application and secure with decompiler

Tags: android, proguard

If any have step by step process of using `proguard` in android application then please share.

I have found some information but it hasn't helped. I am doing research since last 3-4 hours but I am failed to find out proper solution.

So if any one knows about `proguard` integration in android, please give me guideline and process for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Progurd can be easily enable using eclipse
[How to obfuscate my android project in eclipse IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119004/how-to-obfuscate-my-android-project-in-eclipse-ide)
check the answer 
or
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

if you want to do it manually check this out
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html

Comment: Yes proguard, i followed http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html this steps and it works successfully for me