# Android Eclipse: Running an Application in Release Mode?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, release

I want to be able to run my Application in `"Release Mode"` in `Eclipse`  so that I can enable `ProGuard`, but I do not know the steps required in order to do so.

I have tried the information at: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html, but I find it quite overwhelming.

Can someone outline the required steps, or provide a link to a simple step by step tutorial?

EDIT: please note that I do not actually wish to release this app on the Play Store, it is just to test if I am correctly enabling ProGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Enable Proguard

Uncomment the line in `project.properties` there's a comment that makes it clear which one.

### Building

As you're using eclipse, I recommend using ant as detailed here: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#ReleaseMode

There is a one time step of:

```
cd projectPath
android update project -p .
```

That creates the `build.xml` for ant. You will need to repeat for sub projects.

Open or create `ant.properties` and put this in:

```
key.store=path/to/my.keystore
key.alias=mykeystore
```

To generate this keystore see http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Then at any time to create a build do:

```
cd projectPath
ant release
```

This will create a signed, aligned and proguarded apk.

Comment: Thank  you for a clear answer, Rather than use ANT however, can I just use "Export unsigned Application Package"? I ask as I am not familiar with ANT

Comment: Note that I tried the method in previous comment, but when I reverse engineered it, the only code that was obfuscated was the Super class "ActionBarActivity". Why was the cource code not also obfuscated?

Comment: Proguard only kicks in on release. You can definitely use export signed application. I don't know if unsigned implies non-release. I don't use eclipse for release builds because (in the past at least) it was unreliable, it would give a meaningless error back during build.

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Yes I read that link thanks, I assume, however, that I have created a release build using "Export unsigned Application Package" as the .apk is a lot smaller than the identical one without proguard, it also includes some obfuscation. Do you know how to configure proguard to obfuscate all source code?

Comment: If it has proguarded, you will have a `mapping.txt` and a three other files from proguard. Do you?

Comment: Yes I Have these files?

Comment: Then it has proguarded. `usage.txt` contains items it has not proguarded. You should ask a specific question about those.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how/have a link to a tutorial that shows how to customize proguard to get it to proguard specific methods/classes etc

Comment: You can read the manual on http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you, do you have any guides as to how to integrate dexguard?

Comment: No, I've not used it. dexguard is, AFAIK, the premium version of proguard.

Answer (score 0):

At first,you must know the functionality of proguard and how to export your application in eclipse ide as a .apk file.Note the below link for your reference.Here,the process explained briefly.

[How to obfuscate my android project in eclipse IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119004/how-to-obfuscate-my-android-project-in-eclipse-ide)

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, However I was under the impression that all needed to integrate proguard was to uncomment a line in Project.properties, then run it in release mode?

Comment: @user999222 Ya correct.The property file contents convert your code as a random text (A-Z,0-9,a-z) hence it could not reverse-engineering by others.After that you can export your project as .apk file by adding functionality like key stores and passwords.

Comment: Thanks, Can I use "Export unsigned Application Package" to build my application with proguard In it? I tried this, but when I reverse engineered it, the only code that was obfuscated was the Super class "ActionBarActivity".