# Why do not export the Signed application package no worked?

Tags: android, obfuscation

when I try to export signed application package everything is OK but when I click the Finish button everything is goes to wait mode and APK file not generated. 
[image: Screenshot]
please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proguard is part of the android eclipse plugin, so you do not have to invoke it manually. You just need to activate it on your build.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119004/how-to-obfuscate-my-android-project-in-eclipse-ide).

Comment: this works for me. Simple steps to obfuscate your .apk file. tanx