# Shrinking the size of an apk

Tags: android, eclipse

All the drawable and raw files have 900kbs all together  in my application, but the entire size of the application is comming ouut to be 5.5 Mbs. I am working in eclipse and google play services library along with appcompact_v7 library are attached.

How can i shrink the size of my exported apk file. Because my application is way too simple to have 5.5 Mbs.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: check assests, lib/s folder remove uncessary files, jars..

Answer (score 3):

Use Android [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) tool. The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

Comment: how do i use proguard in the presence of these libraries, any tutorial you may recommend?

Comment: @AleemAhmed - I have added a link in my answer, there you will find steps to use ProGuard in Android Studio. This is the most easiest way to do.

Comment: But for now i am using eclipse, any help for it?

Answer (score 2):

First, consider switching to Android Studio and using a subset of Google Play Services, for whatever part you are using. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup) has a "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" section that covers this.

Second, if you are examining the size of your debug build, bear in mind that release builds use ProGuard to get rid of extraneous Java code, and so your releae APK will be a bit smaller.

Beyond that, Cyril Mottier has a [great blog post](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/) on "Putting Your APKs on a Diet". However, some of the more powerful techniques, such as eliminating resources from Play Services via `resConfigs`, require Android Studio.

Comment: An excellent blog post - a must read for Android devs regardless of experience level

Answer (score 0):

There are some techniques you could achieve this:

- Proguard - to remove unused classes from your final apk
- "lint --check UnusedResources " - detect resources that your app has and are not being used
- Use helper jar: https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/

You can read this Android official doc for more info : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking .

Comment: How do i use that any tutorial?

Comment: For using Proguard with Eclipse, you can check these answers (very straightforward): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119004/how-to-obfuscate-my-android-project-in-eclipse-ide